# Audio.search не возвращает все найденные песни?

Tags: vkontakte-api, android-vksdk

Привет. Не знаю это баг или сами девелоперы так сделали. Исползваю `VK API` на андроиде. Вот запрос готов, отправляю с работающей токеном, а ответ не совпадает с ответом если я это сделаю на сайте  [`API`](https://vk.com/dev/audio.search). Этот несовпадение от количества и список песен. Пример такой: самый простой запрос, `Q="twenty one pilots ride"` и `count 5`(это сколка песен в максимум отправить в ответе) . В приложение ответ такой: `count`(количества песен удовлетворяющий данную ключевое слова) ровно `4187`, о количество что отправлена мне штук `3`, а должна была `5`. Тоже самое в сайте: `count 4191` , возвращает `5` песен, которые первые `2` не было в ответе от запроса в моем приложение, и сама собой, эти первые `2` песни самые подходящие. Кто та столкнулся с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблемы могут быть в двух местах:

1. Вы забыли передать параметр `v` (версию API), из-за чего всё работает наперекосяк.
2. Песни, которых не хватает в ответе, защищены копирайтом. Насколько мне известно, только официальным приложениям возвращаются защищенные копирайтом песни, а консоль API также считается официальным приложением. Как вариант, можете попробовать делать запросы к [`audio.search`](https://vk.com/dev/audio.search), [притворяясь официальным приложением](https://habrahabr.ru/post/213163/).

Comment: так как уже такой подход не работает. Надо копаться в апк может найду что нибудь. 100% девелопер добавляет какой та параметр